# How to solve k8s persistentvolume-controller no volume plugin matched for kubeadm

Tags: kubernetes, local-storage, kubeadm

I have configured a kubernetes cluster on bare metal using kubeadm. Everything works well and I can deploy an example nginx app. Problem comes in when I want to deploy a statefulset with `volumeClaimTemplates` as shown below

```
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: jackrabbit-volume
    spec:
      accessModes:
      - ReadWriteOnce
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 2Gi
      storageClassName: jackrabbit
```

and the storageclass

```
allowVolumeExpansion: true
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  annotations:
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: chart-1591185140
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: gluu
    storageclass.beta.kubernetes.io/is-default-class: "false"
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    storage: jackrabbit
  managedFields:
  - apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
mountOptions:
- debug
parameters:
  fsType: ext4
  pool: default
provisioner: kubernetes.io/no-provisioner
reclaimPolicy: Retain
```

I have also tried to add a `persistentVolume` with `hostPath` spec but still not working.

```
 ----     ------              ----               ----                         -------
  Warning  ProvisioningFailed  82s (x3 over 98s)  persistentvolume-controller  no volume plugin matched
```

Comment: is `metadata.name: jackrabbit.fullname` is missing from storageclass?

Comment: Hey @hoque the name is there. when I do `kubectl get sc` i can see it.

Comment: Hello, did you had time to check my answer?

Answer (score 2):

In your StorageClass you are using `kubernetes.io/no-provisioner` and this means you are trying to use Local Volume Plugin.

You cluster doesn't know `kubernetes.io/no-provisioner` yet and that's why `no volume plugin matched` is presented.

According to [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes),  this Plugin is not included in the `kubernetes.io` as an Internal Provisioner. [Here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/#provisioner) you can see a chart listing all Provisioners, their Plugin Names, if they are included in the Internal Provisioner and a link to a config example.

In the documentation we can read:

> You are not restricted to specifying the “internal” provisioners
>   listed here (whose names are prefixed with `kubernetes.io` and shipped
>   alongside Kubernetes). You can also run and specify external
>   provisioners, which are independent programs that follow a 
>   [specification](https://git.k8s.io/community/contributors/design-proposals/storage/volume-provisioning.md)
>   defined by Kubernetes. Authors of external provisioners have full
>   discretion over where their code lives, how the provisioner is
>   shipped, how it needs to be run, what volume plugin it uses (including
>   Flex), etc. The repository 
>   [kubernetes-sigs/sig-storage-lib-external-provisioner](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/sig-storage-lib-external-provisioner)
>   houses a library for writing external provisioners that implements the
>   bulk of the specification. Some external provisioners are listed under
>   the repository 
>   [kubernetes-incubator/external-storage](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/external-storage).
>
> For example, NFS doesn’t provide an internal provisioner, but an
>   external provisioner can be used. There are also cases when 3rd party
>   storage vendors provide their own external provisioner.

The Local external provisioner is maiteined on [this](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/sig-storage-local-static-provisioner#getting-started) GitHub repository and there you can find the [Getting Started](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/sig-storage-local-static-provisioner#getting-started) guide that will lead you trough how to use it.

Comment: Hey there. Apologies it took me long to reply. I managed to fix the issue. Your explanation was great and it helped alot. However, I just used a very simple `StorageClass` with `kubernetes.io/no-provisioner` and worked.

Comment: Glad it worked. If your solution includes more and relevant findings, please go ahead and post an answer explaining everything. This way others can get help if they face similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

The `no volume plugin matched` error from the *persistentvolume-controller* usually appears (when describing the PVC) when there was a **problem with the allocation of a PV to the PVC**.

To verify this - run `kubectl describe` on the pods / statefulsets - if you see the error of:

```
... pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims
```

This can be caused due to multiple reasons when working a **local volume** - a few examples:

1 ) The PVC is requesting too much storage and there is no PV that can satisfy this value (the PV storage value need to be equal or higher then the PVC storage requests).

2 ) Not all PVC as a corresponding PV - in the case we can see that some resources will be succesful and some will be stuck:

```
$ kubectl get pods
NAME      READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
mongo-0   2/2     Running   0          3m38s
mongo-1   0/2     Pending   0          3m23s

$ kubectl get pvc
NAME                               STATUS    VOLUME           CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS    AGE
mongo-persistent-storage-mongo-0   Bound     mongo-local-pv   50Gi       RWO            local-storage   80m
mongo-persistent-storage-mongo-1   Pending
```

3 ) When the scheduler failed to match a node to the PV.

When using local volumes, the `nodeAffinity` of the PV is required and should be a value of an existing node in the cluster.